# Codeigniter Form Validation library "Field is required" even having a value

Tags: php, codeigniter

Getting database data from two select inputs shows that one of my select input is empty. It tells me that it is required when in fact it has a value.

This is my view with its javascript

```
<div class="row entry">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="text-danger">Main Category</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="form-main-category-type" data-form-type="sample" id="form-main-category-type" data-target="form-sub-category-type" data-url="<?php echo base_url("dashboard/staff/inventory/find_sub_category"); ?>" required>
                <option value=""></option>
                <?php foreach($param_categories as $category) {?>
                <option value="<?php echo $category['main_category'];?>"><?php echo $category['main_category'];?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="text-danger">Sub Category</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="form-sub-category-type" data-form-type="sample" id="form-sub-category-type" data-url="<?php echo base_url("dashboard/staff/inventory/get_items"); ?>" required>
                <option value=""></option>

            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#dataTableInventory').DataTable();

        $.subCategoryHandler = {
            getSubCategories: function(obj) {
                $(obj).parents('.entry').find('select[name="'+obj.data('target')+'"] option').each(function(){$(this).remove();});
                $(obj).parents('.entry').find('select[name="'+obj.data('target')+'"]').append('<option value=""></option>');
                $.post(obj.data('url'), {main_category:$(obj).val()}, function(data) {
                    if (data.ret) {
                        $.each(data.sub_categories, function(key, val) {
                            $(obj).parents('.entry').find('select[name="'+$(obj).data('target')+'"]').append('<option value="'+ val +'">'+ val +'</option>');
                        });
                    }
                }, 'json');
            },
            getItems: function(obj) {
                console.log($('#form-main-category-type').val());
                console.log($(obj).val());
                $.post(obj.data('url'), {main_category:$('#form-main-category-type').val(),sub_category:$(obj).val()}, function(data) {
                    if (data.ret) {
                        console.log(data.item_data);
                    }
                }, 'json');
            }
        };

        $('#form-main-category-type').change(function() {
            $.subCategoryHandler.getSubCategories($(this));   
        });

        $('#form-sub-category-type').change(function() {
            $.subCategoryHandler.getItems($(this));   
        });

    });
</script>
```

And this is my controller

```
public function find_sub_category()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $main_category = $this->input->post('main_category');

        $this->form_validation->set_data(array('form-main-category-type'=>$main_category));
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('form-main-category-type', 'Main Category', 'required');
        if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
            echo json_encode(array('ret'=>0));
            return;
        }

        $staffInfo = $this->staffinfo_model->selectItem(array('member_idx'=>$this->session->userdata('member_index')),'department_group');
        $items = $this->inventoryinfo_model->getItemsArray(array('main_category'=>$main_category, 'department_owner'=>$staffInfo->department_group), 'sub_category');

        $sub_categories = array_unique(array_map(function($i) { return $i['sub_category']; }, $items));

        echo json_encode(array('ret'=>1, 'sub_categories'=>$sub_categories));
    }

    public function get_items()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $main_category = $this->input->post('main_category');
        $sub_category = $this->input->post('sub_category');

        $this->form_validation->set_data(array('form-main-category-type'=>$main_category));
        $this->form_validation->set_data(array('form-sub-category-type'=>$sub_category));
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('form-main-category-type', 'Main Category', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('form-sub-category-type', 'Sub Category', 'required');
        if (!$this->form_validation->run()) {
            echo validation_errors();
            return;
        }

        $staffInfo = $this->staffinfo_model->selectItem(array('member_idx'=>$this->session->userdata('member_index')),'department_group');
        $items = $this->inventoryinfo_model->getItemsArray(array('main_category'=>$main_category, 'sub_category'=>$sub_category, 'department_owner'=>$staffInfo->department_group));
        var_dump($items);
        // echo json_encode(array('ret'=>1, 'item_data'=>$items));
    }
```

The `find_sub_category(`) method in my controller works and also the form validation. But when I run the get_items(), it says that `<p>The Main Category field is required.</p>`. I checked both of my data, the sub_category and main_category but both has data on them. I tried commenting the form validation and it really returned some data, meaning both have value on them.

Now why does form validation say it is required when in fact it has data on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('form-main-category-type', 'Main Category', 'required');
```

to

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('main_category', 'Main Category', 'required');
```

Comment: Accepting this answer after 10 minutes. I didnt realize that I didnt use the post names in the set_rules. Thanks mate!